# Where should I ask Node.js related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where should I ask Node.js or anything related to server-side JavaScript questions?

Can anyone suggest me the right place?

Comment: Stack Overflow is as good a place as any: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js

Comment: thanks ... for redirecting me to the right place

Comment: answer, @KevΩ not a comment :P

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the question. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) has [questions tagged node.js](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/node.js) too, such as *[Criteria for choosing a server to run Node.js](https://serverfault.com/questions/184070/criteria-for-choosing-a-server-to-run-node-js)*.

If the question is about using Node.js as a programmer, then [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is the place where to ask the question, using the tag [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js).

Answer (score 4):

Normally on Stack Overflow, it's described as:

> Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers